# Is this a dependant clause?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

I was wondering if the following was a dependent clause:

> There weren’t enough beds, **so I had to sleep on the floor.**

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I believe it is dependent as it doesn't form a complete idea on its own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is composed of two independent clauses joined by the [coordinating conjunction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Coordinating_conjunctions) *so*.

If you wrote instead

> Because there weren’t enough beds I had to sleep on the floor

you transform it into a dependent *because*-clause and an independent clause, because *because* is a subordinating conjunction.